# Не меняется генератор при смене в расширении CMake Tools

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

При попытке смены генератора проекта с `Ninja` который используется по умолчанию, ничего не меняется.

Т.е. я в настройках меняю тип генератора, но в итоге расширение продолжает использовать генератор `Ninja`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файлы настроек:

```
{
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
    "cmake.generator": "Unix Makefiles"
}
```

Однако, при сборке любого проекта, `VSCode` упорно продолжает использовать `Ninja`:

```
[main] Настройка папки: stack_overflow 
[proc] Выполнение команды: D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -Hd:/msys64/home/ヒミコ/dev/stack_overflow -Bd:/msys64/home/ヒミコ/dev/stack_overflow/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - works
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: D:/msys64/home/ヒミコ/dev/stack_overflow/build
```

Используемые расширения:

1. [CMake](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=twxs.cmake)
2. [CMake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)

Можно ли это как то исправить?

Comment: измените из консоли `cmake -G "Ninja"`

Comment: Дело в том что он его по умолчанию использует, но на другой менять не хочет, из консоли все нормально.

Comment: а да, неправильно уловил, я почему то подумал что вы пытаетесь изменить на `Ninja` генератор. Ну если из консоли все работает - то проблема явно кривом плагине